# Find the maximum of the following function of summation

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, optimization

I ran into this problem:
$$f(\sigma)= \sum_{i=\sigma-1}^{n-1} \Bigg (\frac{\sigma-1}{i} \Bigg)^2$$
Find the maximum of this function with $1<\sigma<n$,$n>4$. My conjecture is that it achieves max with $\sigma=\frac{n}{2}+1$ when $n$ is even and $\sigma=\frac{n-1}{2}+1$ when $n$ is odd (according to a simulation). However I cannot prove this. Any hint on what I can do?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I haven't done the exact calculation but with these kind of problems, it sometimes helps to compute $f(\sigma+1)-f(\sigma)$ and check for which values of $\sigma$ this is positive or negative.

Comment: thanks for the comment. the biggest problem for me is that it is not even continuous, so I cannot just integrate. Which branch of maths deal with these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sigma -1=p$, so
$$S=\sum_{i=p}^{n-1} \frac{p^2}{i^2} \le \sum_{i=p}^{n-1} \frac{p^2}{i(i-1)}=p^2\sum_{i=p}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{i-1}-\frac{1}{i}\right)=p^2\left( \frac{1}{p-1}-\frac{1}{n-2}\right)$$
Lastly we have used telescopic summing, so
$$\implies S(p)\le p^2\left( \frac{1}{p-1}-\frac{1}{n-2}\right), p=\sigma -1, \sigma\ge 1.$$
when $n \to \infty$, $S(p)< \frac{p^2}{p-1}=p+1+1/(p-1)$

Comment: sorry but I do not see how this is useful. I am looking for the exact maximum, not the upper bound

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

For $\sigma > 2$ we have

$$
(\sigma-1)^2\left(\frac{1}{\sigma-2}-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\le f_n(\sigma)\le (\sigma-1)^2\left(\frac{1}{\sigma-1}-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)
$$

In black the plot for $f_{100}(\sigma)$

[image]